# Need help for complex data sort SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help for complex data sort from database. Suppose my data stored in table like this:

```
Description
--------------
JCB Excavator - ECU P/N: 728/35700
Geo Prism 1995 GEO - ABS #16213899 GEO pump
Geo Prism 1995 - GEO ABS #16213897
Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213897
Ersatz Airbags, Gurtstrammer und Auto Körper  Teile
this test JCB pipe & JCB pump
Wie man BBA reman erreicht
```

7 rows are there. I want to write a SQL query in such a way as a result it will sort data based on my input word. Suppose my search term is `GEO,JCB` two words together separated by comma. The rows that will come first are those where search word found maximum time. So for `GEO` the word has the maximum time in most of the rows.

Two sorts will be required:

- first sort data in such way where search term found maximum time.
- second sort data on the basis maximum occurrence of search term found in each rows.

Suppose `GEO` the search term found in maximum row.

So all the rows that have `GEO` keyword will come first and then `JCB` related data will come.

In `GEO` related data those rows will come first that have maximum `GEO` keyword.

So the output will be look like.

```
Description
--------------
Geo Prism 1995 GEO - ABS #16213899 GEO pump
Geo Prism 1995 - GEO ABS #16213897
Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213897
this test JCB pipe & JCB pump
JCB Excavator - ECU P/N: 728/35700
Ersatz Airbags, Gurtstrammer und Auto Körper  Teile
Wie man BBA reman erreicht
```

Please help me to construct this kind of sql which will work in all SQL Server version.

Comment: Do you *have* to use SQL Server as a text based search engine (like Luence) may be a better solution. SQL Server isn't great at parsing strings (which is what you'll have to do)

Comment: **ALL** SQL Server versions - wow - how far back?? SQL Server 4.2? 6.0? 6.5? 7.0? 2000? ......

Comment: i am working with sql server 2000....so marc_s can u please help me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Write a function to tokenize a string into a table of words. eg: [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)
2. Apply this function to the search string and the description table
3. Join the two results with cross apply; group the results, count and sort.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
declare @t table(Description varchar(1000))
insert into @t
select 'JCB Excavator - ECU P/N: 728/35700 ' union all
select 'Geo Prism 1995 GEO - ABS #16213899 GEO pump ' union all
select 'Geo Prism 1995 - GEO ABS #16213897 ' union all
select 'Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213897 ' union all
select 'Ersatz Airbags, Gurtstrammer und Auto Körper  Teile ' union all
select 'this test JCB pipe & JCB pump ' union all
select 'Wie man BBA reman erreicht'

declare @search_term varchar(100)
set @search_term ='GEO'
select Description from @t
order by len(Description)-len(replace(Description,@search_term,'')) desc
```

Result

```
Description
----------------------------------------------------------
Geo Prism 1995 GEO - ABS #16213899 GEO pump 
Geo Prism 1995 - GEO ABS #16213897 
Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213897 
Ersatz Airbags, Gurtstrammer und Auto Körper  Teile 
this test JCB pipe & JCB pump 
Wie man BBA reman erreicht
JCB Excavator - ECU P/N: 728/35700
```

Comment: my search term could be also multiple word separated by comma like search_term='GEO,JCB'